# Provision to do some custom cleanup work through "ContainerRequestFilter" on shutdown

Tags: jax-rs, jersey-2.0, servlet-filters

I have some filters implementing `javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter` and registering this filter through implementing `javax.ws.rs.container.DynamicFeature.configure(ResourceInfo, FeatureContext)` as below:

```
context.register(filter);
```

Now there is some cleanup worked to be performed through that filter implementaion on shutdown, I have tried that through `org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.ContainerLifecycleListener.onShutdown(Container)` as well as `org.glassfish.jersey.server.monitoring.ApplicationEventListener.onEvent(ApplicationEvent)`

But somehow I am not able to get the reference of this filter to call its destroy method inside of these above both listener methods.

Below of some compulsion:

- Cannot make filer class as Singleton.
- Cannot mark this filer class with `Provider` annotation. As there may be different type of filters need to be register on basis of different use-case.

Comment: I guess the filters are tied to the resource methods and cannot be accessed the same way as global providers. One work-around I could see is to just manage your own list of providers any using a service. You could inject the service both into the dynamic feature and the application listener.